# Swift 3: Find index and remove an item from array inside an array of Structs

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, struct

I am using struct to populate a Table View Controller with sections and rows. Now I need to remove a cell from the table. How can i find the element inside the lists to remove it?

Struct:

```
struct Cells {
    var section: String!
    var list: [String]!
}
```

Sections and rows

```
var tableStructure = [Cells(section: "Requests", list: ["uidU", "uidV"])]
```

Code to search in the struct the element i want to remove from list, to remove item from struct list and then to remove the cell from table view:

```
let index = tableStructure.index(where: {$0.section == "Requests" && list.index{$0 == cell.selectedUserUid} as Any as! Bool})
self.tableStructure.remove(at: index!) //***ERROR HERE***
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I set a breakpoint to see the content of "cell.selectedUserUid" and it is equal to the element i want to remove from struct.

Suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of `index` is always `Int?` that means it can be `Int` or `nil` but never `Bool` (by the way *`as Any as! Bool`* is a horrible syntax).

You might want this (the `list` array contains the `Uid`)

```
tableStructure.index(where: {$0.section == "Requests" && $0.list.contains(cell.selectedUserUid)})
```

and you <strike>should</strike> **must** safely write

```
if let index = tableStructure.index(where: {$0.section == "Requests" && $0.list.contains(cell.selectedUserUid)}) {
    self.tableStructure.remove(at: index)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

**Edit**

Your design cannot work. You are going to remove the entire section which is not intended. Add a mutating function to your struct (or use a class) to remove the particular **item** in the `list`. Then recreate the corresponding `indexPath`. If the array is empty then you might remove the section.

---

Important note:

**Never ever** declare properties / members in a class / struct as implicit unwrapped optionals which are going to be initialized with an `init` method. If you want an optional use a regular optional (`?`) otherwise a non-optional (no `?` or `!`)

Comment: Thank you for help. I changed the code and removed the item using the code bellow:
    if let indexStructSection = tableStructure.index(where: {($0?.section == "Requests")}){
                    tableStructure[indexStructSection]?.list = tableStructure[indexStructSection]?.list?.filter() { $0 != cell.selectedUserUid }
            }